# LIBGDX, using device like a car-wheel

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm making simple 3d car racing game using LIBGDX,

but I have no idea how to make my (Android) device uses like a car-wheel.

Does anyone could give me a sample code to take a angle of device? (like a car-wheel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that can easily be done with the built in accelerometer api:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Accelerometer

they also linked a demo project where they make use of the accelerometer input:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can I get angle of device with accelerometer apis?